# Remove empty values before form submit jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have form with several text inputs.

When user clicks submit on this form - text input field values being serialized and become parameters of GET request like this

```
?param1+=26482&param2=
```

I need to check: if parameter has no value then remove it. So only parameters with values will be appended to GET request.

How it should be done?

My submit function

```
$("body").on('click','#form_submit_button', function(e){
    var form = $('#filter_form');
    change_url('?'+form.serialize());
});

function change_url(link)
{
    var IE = IE || 0;

    if (IE == 0) {
        var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
        history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", link);
    } else {
        location.href = link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following js which filter your form including only inputs with a value.

http://jsfiddle.net/63ux5ap9/

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#filter_form').submit(function () {
            var text = $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
                return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
            }).serialize();
            console.log('text: ', text);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: +1 for submit event instead of click and use of `:input` (you forgot to  include the jQuery lib in you fiddle)

Comment: *"that works, but not as it should"* What in the world does that mean?

Comment: @Brewal I have added jQuery lib. Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery `$.fn.serialize` is a combination of `$.param` and `$.fn.serializeArray` methods:

```
jQuery.fn.serialize = function () {
    return jQuery.param(this.serializeArray());
}
```

It means that in order to achiever what you are after you can use the same approach and perform additional filtering of the resulting array returned by `serializeArray`:

```
var form = $('#filter_form'),
    params = $.param(form.serializeArray().filter(function(el) {
        return $.trim(el.value);
    }));

change_url('?' + params);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need is:

```
var i = str.lastIndexOf("&");
```

So

```
if(str.length <= str.lastIndexOf("=")) {
   var i = str.lastIndexOf("&");
   str = str.substring(0, i); 
}
```

By the way, I would remove problem from radix!